# RSpec not_to does not show the correct result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Below is my code example.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ hehe$ irb
2.1.2 :001 > require 'rspec/expectations'
 => true 
2.1.2 :002 > include RSpec::Matchers
 => Object 
2.1.2 :003 > expect(4).to be_nil
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected: nil
     got: 4
    from /Users/hehe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.3/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:30:in `fail_with'
    from /Users/hehe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.3/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:37:in `handle_failure'
    from /Users/hehe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.3/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:48:in `handle_matcher'
    from /Users/hehe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.3/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:54:in `to'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/hehe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.2 :004 > expect(4).not_to be_nil
 => false
```

Since `4` is not nil and I expect `expect(4).not_to be_nil` to return true instead of `false`. Could anyone help to explain it?

Comment: RSpec doesn't return true or false. It's point is to force tests to fail by raising an error when an expectation is not met. If it simply returned false, the test wouldn't fail. Try it yourself: write a small test that just calls `false`. The test pasts. Tests pass if no errors are risen, not if the last statement evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `false` doesn't mean it failed, it just means `4` isn't `nil`. If it failed, it would have raised an error.

RSpec uses a `NegativeOperatorMatcher` class to test `not_to` expectations ([source code here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/operators.rb#L111)):

```
class NegativeOperatorMatcher < OperatorMatcher
  def __delegate_operator(actual, operator, expected)
    return false unless actual.__send__(operator, expected)
    fail_with_message("expected not: #{operator} #{expected.inspect}\n         got: #{operator.gsub(/./, ' ')} #{actual.inspect}")
  end
end
```

So basically, it returns false unless the actual value equals the expected value, in which case it continues on to fail the spec (i.e. there's no situation where a negative matcher like `not_to` will ever return `true`).